# windows phone 7.5 mango app size limit

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

What is the size limit for an mango windows phone app?

i know that the size limit for a NoDo app is 225 mb. Does the limit remain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know yes, there havent been any announcements I came across that addressed different limits for your App Sizes,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184844(v=VS.92).aspx

however there have been changes made to the amount of memory they are allowed to use on devices with 256mb or less the limit is 90mb of RAM and I am unsure how high the limit would be for devices with more than 256mb or RAM

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184840(v=VS.92).aspx

There is no Limit on the space of files taken in IsolatedStorage, ApplicationStorage which is temporary can be up to 4mb in size and will be  lost when the application is Closed

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of the XAP package file is 225 MB. I haven't seen any changes in this from Microsoft.

Comment: does the size reffer also to insolated storage?